# Using regression coefficients as primary outcome in an RCT,? Survival +frailty and Power

Tags: correlation, survival, cox-model, statistical-power, random-allocation

I'm doing a multicenter RCT for a PhD, where i compare learning 30 skills for staying calm  (while suicidal)

ACTIVE:with an adjunct  cellphone-app training the skills and

CONTROL:without cellphone app support.

I'm thinking that I'll let the primary outcome be **slope of skills acquisition**. Since there is 30 different skills to learn over 300 days I figure that I could let the slope of :
                "mean days required to learn each skill" 
be the outcome. Say control condition(no phone) took 8.2 days per learned skill and phone condition took 7.1 days per learned skill. after doing linear regression. so 2 very basic questions:

a) say I, instead of this did  (survival curve type acquisition curve,  could i credibly use the Cox-regression coefficient at skill 15 (time-to event) as a reliable primary outcome of the RCT? Survival analysis w. shared frailty using each learned skill as an "event"

b) Could you eventually point me towards ressources to figure out power-calculations while doing this approach
Would be very thankful for feedback, even if this seems very basic, I need a small push to get the ball rolling. I'm a bit puzzled, is it very unconventional to do power analysis for longitudinal data ?

Comment: i cannot see any reason why (a) should not work. Remember you will need to weight the slopes as they will have different sampling variabilities.

Comment: so i need to take variance into account by weighing accordingly...thx. Very helpfull.